# Xcode 15 Integration (Source Control)

Tags: xcode, xcode15

I've used Xcode's source control for years and it has always worked well. However, with Xcode 15 they made some big changes that I am not enjoying (no more side-by-side, etc.).

The biggest issue is I cannot "Stage all" and have to manually select every file individually and stage independently. The stage all button does nothing. I'm thinking this is a bug or maybe I am doing something wrong? See attached for more info. [image]

Comment: Did you try the Integrate -> Stage All Changes menu?

Comment: Yes I did try that option, too.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem, and when I click commit with the changes unstaged and it shows me stage all and commit, it seems to do something, but it doesn't stage the files, so those remain uncommitted.  The "Stage All" button is a NOP.

Comment: Same here. I have a lot of files in the project that are not under git control, and they are shown now every "commit", as unstaged, uncommitted, which is fine. Terrible is that the files that ARE changed will not be committed automatically, you have to manually stage them?? What is this horror?

Comment: I agree, I absolutely hate it. The worst part is the visual merge/diff. Most IDE let you choose the Merge / Diff tools. I may dig into that. Meanwhile I have been using SourceTree to do my commits since Xcode 15.

Comment: Best let Apple know you're not happy via the bugreporter, eh.. feedbackassistant.

Comment: This is horrible, totally unusable, better to downgrade to Xcode 14 again, Xcode rating score is currently 2.9 on app store, how much lower could it be?

Comment: I don't understand this new system at all. Is there a way (other than going back to Xcode 14) to make it do what it used to? Just show me which files have changed and what the changes are, and give me checkboxes?

Comment: v. 15.0.1 - I'm not sure if they fixed it or not, but I personally never use this buttons, I just hit commit and it asks me to stage&commit, and I say yes. It works. The only annoying thing is that you have to select the top item ("Uncommitted changed"). If you happened to stay on an individual file, it just commit this one file instead.

Comment: I'm ready to see a raft of bugs as developers who have logged 1000's of hours on the old system re-orient themselves to these gratuitous changes.  Reviewing changes is such a critical part of my work flow.

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to achieve similar side by side as before, which you can try.

There are two buttons that need to be enabled:

[image]

Comment: I have no idea what this is or how it relates to the question. The question is not how to do a side-by-side code review. That's not the same screen that you do a commit from where the Stage All option is presented.  Maybe you should just delete your answer. It's confusing, not relevant to the question and IMO does not help at all.

Comment: Look closer, he blotted out his code and files, so it’s a little confusing. But he circled two buttons. One in upper right (which is side by side compare) another in lower left (select only files with source-control status). It's not similar to how it was before it's exactly how it was before :)

Comment: Any way to get this behavior in the Source Control -> Changes naviagator? 
(I detest inline diff view!)

Comment: Not having side-by-side when commit is very annoying. I'm not sure about you guys, but I always get confused when deleted and added lines are mixed together and only diff by color.